Stored procedure error ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
I have a stored procedure which uses DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR and returns more than 4000K. This procedure fails with an error ORA-06502. What is the way around this error?
Concatenate 4000K output into multiple results generates another error

ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

No issues when the clob datatype is under 4000K.
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST1 (v_lotNum in varchar, cur_data_out out sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
open cur_data_out for
SELECT
CASE
WHEN l.c_material_info > 0THEN (SELECT DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(note_contents,(LENGTH(note_contents)))FROM
lims_notes WHERE note_id = l.c_material_info)
ELSE 'None'
END AS "Reminder"
FROM lot l
WHERE l.t_ph_interface_login = 'T'
AND l.inspection_lot_num = v_lotNum;
END TEST1;

When executing this code, I'm getting the error. What is the work around to return more than 4000K in this case?
SQL> var mycursor refcursor; SQL> begin TEST1 ( v_lotNum => 80000169781, cur_data_out => :mycursor); end; / 2 3 4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print mycursor ERROR: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small ORA-06512: at line 1

no rows selected


Why are you passing LENGTH(note_contents) to SUBSTR? That will try to get the entire length, though even that call with fail with CLOBs larger than 32k. If you want to limit to 4000 characters then pass that as the argument. (Multibyte characters will still be a problem). You could also just return the whole CLOB and let the caller deal with that, perhaps?

Alex, Thank you for your comment. I need to get all the clob data and convert it to the varchar for the user to see it. I don't need only 4000 chars , I need everything.

So just return the whole CLOB? Otherwise the caller will have to piece it back together. You could split it into multiple rows but that's a bit awkward both for you and the caller, and depending on how they'd use it you might need to figure out how to split it at convenient points - if it has newline characters, and/or hitting whitespace so words aren't split. There are examples here of how to do that but I'd avoid it if you can. Why can the caller only have varchar and not CLOB?

so you are saying just use 'SELECT CLOBCOLUMN FROM TABLE' instead of using DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR?

If the caller can handle that in the result set, then yes - if there's a (good) reason not to then you'll need to look at alternatives, but might as well start with the simple approach...

I just checked with the app team and they confirmed that the app can't handle the clob data. I tried to concatenate the result, but got ORA-01489 result of string concatenations is too long. What are my other options?

You'll either have to truncate it, or split it into multiple chunks of less 4k - then it's the app team's problem to put it back together.

@mspart, the limit of varchar2 in SQL is 4000 bytes, that's why all attempts at converting or concatenating don't work - you simply cannot work with a value > 4000 in SQL without using a LOB. It isn't a matter of LOB vs. varchar2, it's a matter of the 4000 byte ceiling above which a LOB is the only possibility. You will have to work with your app team to figure out how they plan to retrieve a > 4000 byte value and code to that. Internally it will involve multiple round trips to piece together. Unless it can accept an array - then you can return an array of varchar2, breaking up the CLOB.

@mspart, are you printing a var in sqlplus just to demo the issue, or is that how you pull the data for the app (via spool file?)? Also, why use a ref cursor for this instead of a normal simple SQL?
